# Assign multiple conditional values to percentiles into a new pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, percentile

I have the following dataframe with percentiles and I would like to assign values between 0-9 to their respective percentiles.

This is the input:

```
         a
 1  0.3038
 2  0.0572
 3  0.1153
 4  0.2168
 5  0.5688
 6  0.6291
 7  0.9416
 8  0.7438
 9  0.2242
10  0.5662
```

And this is the desired output:

```
         a  b
 1  0.3038  3
 2  0.0572  0
 3  0.1153  1
 4  0.2168  2
 5  0.5688  5
 6  0.6291  6
 7  0.9416  9
 8  0.7438  7
 9  0.2242  2
10  0.5662  5
```

Also, if the value in column 'a' is 1.00 I would like to return the value 9.
For example:

```
        a   b
1  1.0000   9
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated solution**

Thanks to [@Peter Leimbigler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8008776/peter-leimbigler) for the following suggestion in the comments, which makes sure that the requirement that 1.0 maps to 9 is correctly handled:

```
np.floor(df['a']*10).replace({10:9})
```

Alternatively, sticking with the `clip_upper()` idea which was present in the previous solution:

```
np.floor(df.clip_upper(0.9) * 10).astype(int)
```

`0.9` in the above solution can actually be any number `[0.9, 1)`, and will work as intended. The problem in the previous solution is that `1` was used here instead, which meant that a value of exactly `1.0` was not rounded down.

I will leave the original solution below since it was accepted by OP, but as pointed out by [@Peter Leimbigler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8008776/peter-leimbigler), it did not correctly handle the 1.0 -> 9 special case.

---

**Previous solution**

If I understand correctly:

```
df['b'] = np.floor(df.clip_upper(1) * 10).astype(int)
```

Gives the same result as in the question and accounts for your caveat regarding a number that is exactly 1.

```
         a  b
1   0.3038  3
2   0.0572  0
3   0.1153  1
4   0.2168  2
5   0.5688  5
6   0.6291  6
7   0.9416  9
8   0.7438  7
9   0.2242  2
10  0.5662  5
```

Comment: That's my random act of kindness for the day, enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, didn’t know about clip_upper(). Always good to avoid an apply() if possible but couldn’t think of a way in my original answer.

Comment: No worries. If you see me around posting a not-entirely-crap answer, please do consider upvoting. I'll always return the favour.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but what does `clip_upper` achieve here? The current solution `np.floor(df.clip_upper(1) * 10).astype(int)` converts `1.000` to 10 instead of the desired 9, and omitting `clip_upper` doesn't change the output in my (limited) testing. Would a better solution be `np.floor(df['a']*10).replace({10:9})`?

Comment: @Peter Leimbigler - you are right, I will update the answer. Thanks.